# What does cors middleware do?

Tags: node.js, cors

Was looking at some node js code which created some web API's
and came across  this:

```
//CORS Middleware
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,POST,PUT");
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, 
contentType,Content-Type, Accept, Authorization");
next();
});
```

Have looked around on the internet and can't seem to understand what it does?
Can someone please explain the purpose of cors middleware

Comment: Middleware is an express term. Is it York question really about CORS?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does Access-Control-Allow-Origin header work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636611/how-does-access-control-allow-origin-header-work)

Answer (score 14):

This link may help.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api

CORS allows you to configure the web API's security. It has to do with allowing other domains to make requests against your web API. For example, if you had your web API on one server and your web app on another you could configure CORS in your Web API to allow your web app to make calls to your web API.